console.time - How to consistently log in milliseconds
The console.time function in node.js seems to decide which units to display in the log message based on the the length of time that has elapsed. For example:
console.time('timer-ms');
setTimeout(() => console.timeEnd('timer-ms'), 20);
// timer-ms: 20.044ms

console.time('timer-s');
setTimeout(() => console.timeEnd('timer-s'), 2000);
// timer-s: 2.002s

Is it possible to change this behaviour so that the log message always displays the same units, regardless of the time that has elapsed? In the above example, I would want the second output to be timer-s: 2002ms
Note that this is specifically a problem in Node.js and does not appear to be an issue in a browser.

Since log functions aren't there for users, the answer will be no. If you want to do that you will gave to use your own timestamps or performance.now()s and subtract the difference, then convert it to whatever unit you want. Logs are just for debugging,  and as long as it doesn't show inaccurate information, it should make no difference. 2.002s === 2002ms is just a fact and a calculation you can do in youe head.

@somethinghere Who/what are they intended for, then? If log functions arent intended for users, why does JS try to make them more human readable by deciding which is the most human-friendly unit to use? The code I'm working on has a lot of console.time calls  scattered through it. I was hoping to collate some of this data without having to change the code. Perhaps this cant be done from the node application, and instead will need to be handled when parsing the logs

https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#timeend     extract -> in an implementation-defined format.  IOW: Down to the JS implementation, be that Node / Chrome / Firefox etx.

They are intended for developers to read and conclude things from, they are not meant as an input for a the next step (they usually only appear on a console anyway). If you need this, you should mock your own console library and use that, implementing your own timing function and outputting your own desired format.

Side Note:  If you have lots of console.timeEnd code, and since the duration output of timeEnd is none standard, you could potentially just monkey patch console.timeEnd to make the output consistent.  Just keep the format label, U+003A (:), U+0020 SPACE, and duration. to be compliant.. :)

Since the answer presupposes that you're not using a Chromium browser, and Keith's comment suggests this varies between browsers, can you clarify which browser you're experiencing this behaviour in?

@F1Krazy  The OP has a tag with node.js, a quick test here with Node and indeed it uses that format.

Node.js documentation provide:

Use the same label when calling console.timeEnd() to stop the timer and output the elapsed time in suitable time units to stdout. For example, if the elapsed time is 3869ms, console.timeEnd() displays "3.869s".

This is a feature so can't be changed.
If you want to let the unit alike, you can't to use console.time(), please use Date() function instead, don't to use console.time() now. here is an example:
var a = Date.now();
// ...do something
var b = Date.now();

console.log("Used time:", b - a, "ms")

